# If and else with attachment applescript

Tags: applescript

Every day i sent an email with an attached image

I take a screenshot in my iPhone an upload to iCloud, and this appear in my desktop mac, so, my script take this image from desktop, the attached an then send it.

But it needs an “if” or “else” to know if theres an image or not.

If theres an image:send it
If theres not an image: don’t send it

```
set recipientName to "name"
set recipientAddress to "Mail@mail.com"
set theAttachment to POSIX file "user/desktop/image.png"
set theSubject to "theSubject"
set theContent to "message"

--Mail Tell Block
tell application "Mail"

    --Create the message
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

    --Set a recipient
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}
        --Add attachment
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at before the last paragraph


        ##Pause
        delay 3

        ##Send the Message
        --send

    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always address your desktop, it is better to use "path to desktop folder".
Also, use function "exists" to check if the image file exists on your desktop and if not, just you just terminate the script using "return":

```
set theAttachment to ((path to desktop folder) as string) & "image.png"
tell application "Finder"
    if not (theAttachment exists) then return -- image does not exist, then termination
end tell
```

If your script continues after these 4 lines, it means the file image.png exists on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks pbell

it was 

`set theAttachment to POSIX file (system attribute "HOME") & "/Desktop/image.jpg"

tell application "Finder"
 if exists theAttachment then
 else
  log "No image to attach"
 end if
end tell`